# Counting the number of Prüfer codes

Tags: combinatorics

I am given the following problem but I have no idea where to start, any suggestion for this is greatly appreciated!

Consider labeled trivalent rooted trees T with 2n vertices, counting the root labeled 2n. The labels are chosen in such a wah that the procedure leading to $P(T)$ has $1,2,3,...,2n-1$ as a first row. How many possible codes $P(T)$ are there? In this expression $P(T)$ is the Prüfer code.

Comment: What's $P(T)$? From the title it seems it might be the Prüfer code for $T$ -- but a Prüfer code usually doesn't have rows?

Comment: Sorry, yeah it refers to the Prüfer code. I corrected the text. Maybe it might be helpful to say that in my text the Prüfer code is the second row of a $2 x n$ matrix where the first row is the edges of degree 1 we are deleting from the tree and the second row, which is the Prüfer code, is the vertex the corresponding edge of the first row is adjacent to.

Comment: Yes, that would indeed be helpful to say. :-) Generally, if you use conventions and notations that don't appear in [the Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_sequence), that's a safe sign that you should introduce them. It would also be helpful to add that to the question so people don't have to read through the comments to understand the question.

Comment: I think where you wrote "the edges of degree $1$ we are deleting" you meant "vertices"?